# How to uncheck checkbox in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox list and I am not able to uncheck checkbox in React.

```
<input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={
        list?.flag=== "Y" ? true : false
        }
        onChange={(e)=>{
        e.target.value
        }}
/>
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-issue-t6t46x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The CodeSandbox appears to explode with all sorts of CORS errors and IndexedDB errors (Firefox on Linux). The Stack Overflow editor would probably be more robust (as far as I know external scripts can be included in that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it you can check it in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/checkbox-issue-forked-q9n7x4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```js
 const [checkBoxList, setCheckBoxList] = useState([
    {
      name: "one",
      flag: "Y"
    },
    {
      name: "two",
      flag: "Y"
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

For unchecking a checkbox, you need to update the state so it determines whether the checkbox is checked or not

```
      const [checkBox, setCheckBox] = useState([
    {
      name: "one",
      flag: "Y"
    },
    {
      name: "two",
      flag: "Y"
    }
  ]);

    
  const handleCheckBox = (index) => {
    const updatedCheckBox = [...checkBox];
    updatedCheckBox[index].flag = updatedCheckBox[index].flag === "Y" ? "N" : "Y";
    setCheckBox(updatedCheckBox);
  };
    
     return (
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={Checked}
          onChange={handleCheckbox}
        />
      );

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="tw-flex tw-items-start px-2 tw-gap-y-2 tw-gap-x-8 tw-flex-wrap">
        {checkBox && checkBox.map((list, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <label className="tw-flex tw-items-start tw-w-40">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={list.flag === "Y"}
                onChange={() => handleCheckBox(index)}
              />
              {list.name}
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: there is multiple checkbox can you please check codeSandbox I have added in question

Comment: yes, I have checked and updated my code, you can try this.